# Transpose dataframe by replicate dates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18876, 18878, 18876, 18878, 
18876, 18878), class = "Date"), effort = c(2371.5, 1950.66666666667, 
6107.25, 3318.66666666667, 4154.83867521367, 2073.10096153846
), type = c("aerial", "aerial", "TLAcmeth", "TLAcmeth", "TLAmeandaily", 
"TLAmeandaily")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can I transpose this data frame so I have four columns one for the date and one for each "type", it should look like this:

| Date | aerial | TLAcmeth | TLAmeandaily |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-06 | 2371.5 | 6107.25 | 4154.839 |
| 2021-09-08 | 1950.667 | 3318.667 | 2073.101 |

Comment: RyanGary, if the dupe-links and LuccaNielsen's answer do not help, please [edit] your question to show what you've done and why it doesn't work, then @-ping me and we'll work through the issues. If Lucca's works for you, even though I've closed as a dupe (so that the other answers with longer discussions and options can "percolate" to the top of searches), I highly encourage you to accept Lucca's answer. Hope this all works well for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pivot_wider function

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  pivot_wider(id_cols = Date,
                    values_from = effort,
                    names_from = type)



   Date       aerial TLAcmeth TLAmeandaily
  <date>      <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1 2021-09-06  2372.    6107.        4155.
2 2021-09-08  1951.    3319.        2073.
```